# "Moving the instruction pointer can result in unexpected behavior, including crashing your application." Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1

Tags: swift, xcode

This is on this line of code let enemyBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemyBall")

```
@objc func spawnEnem() {

        let enemyBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemyBall")


        self.addChild(enemyBall)
        enemyBall.size = CGSize(width: 25.0, height: 25.0)
        enemyBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemyBall.size.width/2)
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true


        // Physics of our enemy
        enemyBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemyBall.size.width / 2)
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagroy.EnemyHere // setting enemyBall to our physics
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagroy.smallBall | PhysicsCatagroy.mainBall 
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagroy.smallBall | PhysicsCatagroy.mainBall 
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false // we dont want enemy effected by gravity
        enemyBall.name = "Enemy"
}
```

Comment: do you have image named "enemyBall"?

Comment: yep, its in my assets